# Object throwing null pointer exception while running with android Driver using Selenium 3.8.1

Tags: java, android, selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium-android

The Object map is not getting initialised using the android driver. The object is throwing `null pointer exception` whenever trying to use any sendkeys or click.

Please find below the code snippet : -

Code used in  OR :

```
@FindAll({ @FindBy(xpath = "//*[@id='tsbb']") })
    public WebElement Google_homepage__ssearchBTN;

WebDriver driver;
public tesitng_android_om(WebDriver driver){
    this.driver=driver;
}
```

Inside Testcase :

```
        Android driver = new AndroidDriver(sURL, oCap); 

        tesitng_android_om tesitng_android_om = new tesitng_android_om((WebDriver)driver);

        PageFactory.initElements((WebDriver)driver,tesitng_android_om);

        tesitng_android_om.Google_homepage__ssearchBTN.click();
```

The Same code works fine with **Selenium 3.4.0** but is not working in **3.8.1**

Following is the stack trace of the issue :

```
> Error: java.lang.NullPointerException at
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:279)
> at
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.isDisplayed(RemoteWebElement.java:320)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) at
> org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.internal.LocatingElementHandler.invoke(LocatingElementHandler.java:51)
> at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy11.isDisplayed(Unknown Source) at
> org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.elementIfVisible(ExpectedConditions.java:315)
> at
> org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.access$100(ExpectedConditions.java:44)
> at
> org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$10.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:301)
> at
> org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$10.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:298)
> at
> org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$23.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:686)
> at
> org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$23.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:682)
> at
> org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:208)
> at myPackage.library.Android$Helper.checkReady(Android.java:2397) at
> myPackage.library.Android$Web.awType(Android.java:1108) at
> myPackage.testScripts.test_android_tcweb.test(test_android_tcweb.java:64)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) at
> org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
> at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714) at
> org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901) at
> org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231) at
> org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
> at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
> at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767) at
> org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617) at
> org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334) at
> org.testng.SuiteRunner.access$000(SuiteRunner.java:37) at
> org.testng.SuiteRunner$SuiteWorker.run(SuiteRunner.java:368) at
> org.testng.internal.thread.ThreadUtil$2.call(ThreadUtil.java:64) at
> java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) at
> java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
> -- false -- [Expected - True, Actual - False]
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the following code block :

```
tesitng_android_om tesitng_android_om = new tesitng_android_om((WebDriver)driver);
PageFactory.initElements((WebDriver)driver,tesitng_android_om);
```

Replace by :

```
tesitng_android_om tesitng_android_om_page = PageFactory.initElements(driver, tesitng_android_om.class);
```

Comment: Tried with this code too but still the issue is same.